# how do i seperate single post value from foreach loop

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am Building an application in which i have a form with multiple file upload
when the user submits the form then all the post values as catched by foreach loop like this

```
if($booker->setsessions($_POST))
{
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'homes','action'=>'step_four'));
}
else
{
    $this->setFlashMsg('Please Provide Valid Information','message-box ok');
}
```

here it is catching the post values

```
foreach($data as $index=>$value){
    $this->$index=$value;
}
$this->save();  
$booking->booker_id =$this->id;
$booking->save();

public function save() 
{   
    if (!$this->id) {
        $this->create();
    }
    else {
        $this->update();
    }
}

protected function create()
{
    $connection = db::factory('mysql');

    $sql = "insert into {$this->table} (`";
    $sql .= implode('`, `', array_keys($this->values));
    $sql .= "`) values ('";

    $clean = array();
    foreach ($this->values as $value) {
        $clean[] = $connection->clean($value);
    }

    $sql .= implode("', '", $clean);
    $sql .= "')";

    $this->id = $connection->insertGetID($sql);
}
```

here $this->save(); takes all the $index=>values and inserts into one table
my form looks this

```
    <form class="form-3 form-horizontal ajxfrm" id="step-three" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $html->addLink(array('controller'=>'homes','action'=>'step_three_ajax')); ?>" method="post">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    <input id="city" type="text" name="city" />
     <input id="contact" type="text" name="contact" />
     <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload[]" />
```

So here i want to upload all the data in table and files in another table throught mysql
but the above code is taking all the post values and trying to insert in one table in which there is no file column so its giving me an error

Comment: your question is not clear, you should access your files using `$_FILE` not `$_POST`

Comment: I'm Updating the question

Comment: so i get you right, you take all the `$_POST` value and assign them as a property and you want to use table `a` for the files and table `b` for any other informations submitted?

Comment: Also add how you are inserting

Comment: dianuj:- Updated the question